# Wrong type argument: markerp

Tags: elisp

I have some code from "Writing GNU emacs extensions". It is merely a script that allows you to get back to the previous position, kinda like an undo for the buffer position:

```
(put 'scroll-up 'unscrollable t)
(put 'scroll-down 'unscrollable t)
(put 'scroll-left 'unscrollable t)
(put 'scroll-right 'unscrollable t)


(defvar unscroll-point (make-marker)
  "Text position for next call to 'unscroll'.")

(defvar unscroll-window-start nil
  "Window start for next call to unscroll.")

(defvar unscroll-hscroll nil
  "Hscroll for next call to 'unscroll'.")

(defadvice scroll-up (before remember-for-unscroll
                             activate compile)
  "Remember where we started from, for unscroll."
  (unscroll-maybe-remember))

(defadvice scroll-down (before remember-for-unscroll
                             activate compile)
  "Remember where we started from, for unscroll."
  (unscroll-maybe-remember))

(defun unscroll-maybe-remember ()
  (if (not (get last-command 'unscrollable))
      (progn
        (set-marker unscroll-point (point))
        (setq unscroll-window-start (window-start))
        (setq unscroll-hscroll (window-hscroll)))))

(defun unscroll ()
  (interactive)
  (goto-char unscroll-point)
  (set-window-start nil unscroll-window-start)
  (set-window-hscroll nil unscroll-hscroll))
```

Problem is, it does not work. When I try to use `Ctrl-f` and `Ctrl-b`* I get following error below the mode-line: `wrong type argument markerp`

If I change the lines using markers to use points it works.

```
(defvar unscroll-point nil
  "Text position for next call to 'unscroll'.")
```

and

```
(defun unscroll-maybe-remember ()
  (if (not (get last-command 'unscrollable))
      (progn
        (setq unscroll-point (point))
        (setq unscroll-window-start (window-start))
        (setq unscroll-hscroll (window-hscroll))))) ;; I know setq can take multiple arguments
```

I want to use markers since these are robust and are unaffected by buffer edits. How do I fix this code? The book is almost 20 years old, but all the code has worked so far. Dunno if this used to be correct, but isn't anymore.

*are these evil-commands or not? Can't remember...

Here is the debug-info:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument markerp 8245)
  set-marker(8245 176)
  (progn (set-marker unscroll-point (point)) (setq unscroll-window-start (window-start)) (setq unscroll-hscroll (window-hscroll)))
  (if (not (get last-command (quote unscrollable))) (progn (set-marker unscroll-point (point)) (setq unscroll-window-start (window-start)) (setq unscroll-hscroll (window-hscroll))))
  unscroll-maybe-remember()
  ad-Advice-scroll-up(#<subr scroll-up> nil)
  apply(ad-Advice-scroll-up #<subr scroll-up> nil)
  scroll-up(nil)
  evil-scroll-page-down(1)
  funcall-interactively(evil-scroll-page-down 1)
  call-interactively(evil-scroll-page-down nil nil)
  command-execute(evil-scroll-page-down)
```

Comment: Could you please update your post by including a full backtrace? Do `M-x toggle-debug-on-error` and reproduce the error to obtain it.

Comment: Will do tomorrow; can't access the code from home.

Comment: @wasamasa Added the info. To reproduce the error I just need to press `C-f` for `evil-scroll-page-down`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## What's happening

It looks like your `unscroll-point`'s value is a number. That's why `set-marker` fails on it.

Since there's nothing in your first code block that could be
responsible for that, I'm guessing this is some left over state. This
left over state can be caused because `defvar` does not change the
value of a variable that's already set, it only sets the variable's
value the *first* time.
[See here](http://endlessparentheses.com/what-s-a-defconst-and-why-you-should-use-it.html)
for why it's like that.

## How to avoid it

To prevent this from happening again as you develop packages, whenever
you change the value of a `defvar` (or `defcustom`), you need to
reevaluate it with
[`eval-defun`](http://doc.endlessparentheses.com/Fun/eval-defun)
(bound to `C-M-x`), instead of using `C-x C-e`, or `load`ing the file,
or `eval-buffer`. `eval-defun` is designed for developing and forces
the value to be reset even on `defvar`s.

Comment: Wonderful. Thanks! The error must have been that unscroll-point had been a number, but I changed the code to use a marker. For some reason unscroll-point stayed a number even though I reevaled the buffer.

Comment: Probably because defvar does not change non-`nil` values...

Comment: @TheUnfunCat Yes, that's why. Updated the answer with the explanation.